# Need to update 15 min every last column value

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image: Query result screenshot]

```
select ROUTE_DESC,
       TRANSIT_TIME,
       to_timestamp(TIME_DEPART) + 
                     numtodsinterval(TRANSIT_TIME,'HOUR') as "arrival",
       (to_timestamp(TIME_DEPART)
                    +numtodsinterval(nvl(TRANSIT_TIME,0),'HOUR')) 
                          + interval '15' MINUTE as "dept"
  from FE_JPROUTE_SHIP_TMP
 where TRIP_NO='TRP0000464' 
   and GUID='-1259520161' order by SEQ_NO;
```

I want output like this

```
route_desc  transit_time  arraival                          dept
-----------------------------------------------------------------
null        null          25-JUL-17 06.15.00.000000000 AM
null        1             25-JUL-17 07.15.00.000000000 AM   25-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM
null        3             25-JUL-17 10.30.00.000000000 AM   25-JUL-17 10.45.00.000000000 AM
```

[image: Desired result screenshot]

Comment: What's actually stopping you from doing this (whatever it is)? Put some more detailed explanation of you issue and what you tried so far.

Comment: the actual TIME_DEPART is "25-JUL-17 06.00.00.000000000 AM" i want to add TIME_DEPART value to  TIME_DEPART of every row. so it could be  25-JUL-17 06.15.00.000000000 AM
25-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM
25-JUL-17 10.45.00.000000000 AM But actually what i am getting was     25-JUL-17 06.00.00.000000000 AM
25-JUL-17 07.15.00.000000000 AM
25-JUL-17 09.15.00.000000000 AM .so i need to add TRANSIT_TIME to max of dept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Cumulative `SUM()`  - `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` - which is the default in oracle for `SUM () OVER (ORDER BY )`
along with `NULLS FIRST` clause.

Here is a simulation of the query.

```
WITH FE_JPROUTE_SHIP_TMP AS
  (SELECT NULL ROUTE_DESC,
    NULL transit_time,
    '25-JUL-17 06.00.00.000000000 AM' TIME_DEPART
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL ROUTE_DESC,
    1 transit_time,
    '25-JUL-17 06.00.00.000000000 AM' TIME_DEPART
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL ROUTE_DESC,
    3 transit_time,
    '25-JUL-17 06.00.00.000000000 AM' TIME_DEPART
  FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT transit_time,
  arrival,
  NVL2( arrival,arrival + interval '15' MINUTE ,to_timestamp(TIME_DEPART ) + interval '15' MINUTE ) AS "dept"
FROM
  (SELECT transit_time,
    time_depart,
    to_timestamp(TIME_DEPART ) + numtodsinterval(CUMU_TRANSIT_TIME,'HOUR') + numtodsinterval(15*CUMU_DEP_INTV,'MINUTE') arrival
  FROM
    (SELECT transit_time,
      time_depart,
      SUM ( TRANSIT_TIME ) OVER ( ORDER BY transit_time NULLS FIRST ) CUMU_TRANSIT_TIME,
      SUM ( NVL2(TRANSIT_TIME,1,NULL )) OVER ( ORDER BY transit_time NULLS FIRST ) CUMU_DEP_INTV
    FROM FE_JPROUTE_SHIP_TMP
    )
  );
```

You will have to incorporate it in your main query. 
Let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much Kaushik.Its Working Fine.I last value of "dept" column should be null.

Comment: Ok. You are welcome. I checked the image for ur desired o/p. Actually the outputs in the image and your question were slightly different,

Comment: Ya kaushik it was a new requirement.And i solved some other way.Thank you Kaushik.